# Styling the HTML document created by nbconvert

Tags: html, css, themes, jupyter-lab, nbconvert

I try to create a theme for the HTML-file created by `nbconvert`. In the past it was possible to include a `custum.css` which was applied to the produced HTML-file. Nowadays jupyterlabs theme structure is completely different and I want to recreate something similar. My procedure right now is to

1. modify the fonts and sizes in `.conda/envs/my-env/share/jupyter/nbconvert/templates/lab/static/theme-light.css`
2. run `jupyter nbconvert --to html --no-input --theme light my.ipynb`
3. include css commands in the produced HTML-file

The last two steps can be automated by the following script

```py
#!/usr/bin/python
import argparse 
from subprocess import call

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser() 
parser.add_argument('-f') 
args = parser.parse_args() 

filename = args.f
call(f'jupyter nbconvert --to html --no-input --theme light {filename}'.split())

filename = filename.split('.')[0] + '.html'

prefix = """<style>
html {
  background-color: #eeeeee;
  text-align: center;
}

body.jp-Notebook {
  max-width: 1000px;
  display: inline-block;
}
</style>

""" 
  
with open(filename, 'r+') as f: 
    content = f.read() 
    if content[:4] != 'html':
        f.seek(0, 0) 
        f.write(prefix) 
        f.write(content)
```

Now I wonder that the intended way of doing this is. In particular I want to know

1. How to create a theme that is available in nbconvert (I tried [cookiecutter](https://github.com/jupyterlab/extension-cookiecutter-ts) without success)?
2. How to include custom css-code into the output of nbconvert?